# Python code stuck without error in SVC with Scikit-Learn

Tags: python, scikit-learn, svm

I test an SVC model in Scikit-Learn with different parameters. I have nested for loops for the ranges I want to test. However, there is a strange issue. After a certain amount of loops, the code just stuck there without printing anything. No matter how much time I leave it.

```
params_c = [0.1, 1, 10, 100]
params_kernel = ['poly', 'rbf', 'sigmoid']
params_gamma = [0.3, 0.5, 2, 5]
params_degree = [2, 5]

for c in params_c:
    for kernel in params_kernel:
        for gamma in params_gamma:
            for degree in params_degree:

                params = {
                        'c': c,
                        'kernel': kernel,
                        'gamma': gamma,
                        'degree': degree
                        }
                print(params)
                if kernel != 'poly':
                    model = SVC(C = params['c'], kernel = params['kernel'], gamma = params['gamma'])
                    break #no need to iterate for degree
                else:
                    model = SVC(C = params['c'], kernel = params['kernel'], gamma = params['gamma'], degree = params['degree'])


                model.fit(X_train, y_train)
                y_predictions = model.predict(X_test)
```

The code above print the following:

```
{'c': 0.1, 'kernel': 'poly', 'gamma': 0.3, 'degree': 2}
{'c': 0.1, 'kernel': 'poly', 'gamma': 0.3, 'degree': 5}
{'c': 0.1, 'kernel': 'poly', 'gamma': 0.5, 'degree': 2}
{'c': 0.1, 'kernel': 'poly', 'gamma': 0.5, 'degree': 5}
{'c': 0.1, 'kernel': 'poly', 'gamma': 2, 'degree': 2}
{'c': 0.1, 'kernel': 'poly', 'gamma': 2, 'degree': 5}
```

The first iterations take more or less a few seconds (<10secs). Then, after the last one you see on the `print`, it stuck without further printing for more than an hour (after an hour I just stopped the terminal).

I tried to increase the verbose value to get some insights from the SVC, but there isn't any helpful info.

Any idea what is going on?

Comment: Support Vector machines are known to take a large time depending on the data. There are many questions about grid-searching over SVC and hanging.

Comment: On top of that, you are using a polynomial kernel with degree 5 so that will take some time depending on your features. You can try standardizing your dataset to maybe speed it up a little. Other than that, try setting `max_iter` param in SVC to stop it after some iterations